# How to suppress the "Current Location" callout in map view

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mkmapviewdelegate

Tapping the pulsating blue circle representing the userLocation brings up a "Current Location" callout. Is there a way to suppress that?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There's a property on the annotation view you can change, once the user location has been updated:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation
{
    MKAnnotationView *userLocationView = [mapView viewForAnnotation:userLocation];   
    userLocationView.canShowCallout = NO;
}
```

Comment: Sometimes location cannot be determined and MKUserLocation turns gray. Callout is still being displayed in that case. This answer is not correct.

Comment: do this alone doesn't work for me on iOS 10. handling in `viewForAnnotation` works.

Answer (score 16):

You can set the `title` to blank to suppress the callout:

```
mapView.userLocation.title = @"";
```

**Edit:**
A more reliable way might be to blank the title in the `didUpdateUserLocation` delegate method:

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation
{
    userLocation.title = @"";
}
```

or in `viewForAnnotation`:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>) annotation
{
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
    {
        ((MKUserLocation *)annotation).title = @"";
        return nil;
    }

    ...
}
```

Setting the title in the delegate methods lets you be certain you have a real userLocation instance to work with.

Comment: Thanks! I knew i could change the title and subtitle but didn't know setting the title to a blank string would suppress it.

Comment: Answer by @jowie is better.  Use that method instead.

Comment: @Anna been fiddling but haven't had success - any thoughts as to how to suppress the default callout bubble entirely (as above, and yes, @jowie answer probably better) without blocking `mapView:didSelectedAnnotationView:` to be called?

Answer (score 6):

Swift 4

```
// MARK: - MKMapViewDelegate

func mapViewDidFinishLoadingMap(_ mapView: MKMapView) {
    if let userLocationView = mapView.view(for: mapView.userLocation) {
        userLocationView.canShowCallout = false
    }
}
```

Comment: mapView.view(for: mapView.userLocation) seems like the most elegant option indeed! You can also leverage this in the ```mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation)``` callback to group it together with all other annotation views

Answer (score 2):

Swift 4 - Xcode 9.2 - iOS 11.2

```
// MARK: - MKMapViewDelegate

func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
  if let userLocation = annotation as? MKUserLocation {
    userLocation.title = ""
    return nil
  }
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have two ways to help you:

1. suppress in the mapViewDidFinishLoadingMap

   ```
   func mapViewDidFinishLoadingMap(_ mapView: MKMapView) {
   mapView.showsUserLocation = true
   //suppress the title
   mapView.userLocation.title = "My Location"
   //suppress other params
   ```

   }
2. suppress in the didUpdate

   ```
   func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didUpdate userLocation: MKUserLocation) {
       //suppress the title
       mapView.userLocation.title = "My Location"
       //suppress other params
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

## SWIFT Version

We need to set the user `MKAnnotationView` property  `canShowCallout` to false when `mapView` adds the user MKAnnotationView

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didAdd views: [MKAnnotationView]) {
    for view in views {
        if view.annotation is MKUserLocation {
            view.canShowCallout = false
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey there is an updated easy solution

Swift:

```
mapView.userLocation.title = "";
```

.Net for iOS (Xamarin.iOS)

```
NativeMap.UserLocation.Title = "";
```

Regards ;)

Comment: Please don't post identical answers to multiple questions. Instead, tailor the answer to the question asked. If the questions are exact duplicates of each other, please vote/flag to close instead.